# C# Upload Profile Picture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I am making an MVC 4 Web App that includes accounts. I want the accounts to have profile pictures but unfortunately I don't know where to start. I have OAuth set up, is it possible to retrieve a profile picture from the Microsoft, Twitter, Facebook, or Google account provided?

Comment: Probably. Check the documentation of their respective APIs. Or consider using [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can start here for Microsoft Account: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826534.aspx#name_rest

The other identity providers will have a similar mechanism to do the same thing.